# Unable to Write to Pop Up Window Using Object's Attribute textContent

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

I'm trying to write a function that when click on an image, it will open a pop-up window and displays "Hello." The function is called inside a for loop. And I get it to open the pop up window when I click on the image but it only displays "Hello" for 1s and the word disappears.

```
//The object image call the function openNewWindow on click event
lightBox.appendChild(lbImages);
   lbImages.id = "lbImages";
   // Add images from the imgFiles array to the container
   for (let i = 0; i < imgCount; i++) {
      let image = document.createElement("img");
      image.src = imgFiles[i];
      image.alt = imgCaptions[i];
      image.onclick = openNewWindow;
      lbImages.appendChild(image);
   }

//openNewWindow function that opens a pop-up window(newwindow.html) when the image is clicked and also write Hello
function openNewWindow() {
      let newWin = window.open("newwindow.html", "", "width=1000, height=800");
      let mainHeading = document.createElement("h1");
      mainHeading.textContent = "Hello";
      newWin.document.body.appendChild(mainHeading);
      l
   }
```

I tried to use `newWindow.document.write("<h1>My Slideshow</h1>")` and it works. But it doesn't work with the above method. Changing to `mainHeading.innerHTML` also doesn't work.